# List multiplication with nested lists

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, functional-programming

Consider the list of lists

```
thisList = [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

how could I multiple `thisList` so that it would produce another list

```
anotherList = [[1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]
```

I have made the function

```
reps = [1] : map (\ns -> head ns:ns) reps
```

which produces `thisList`

Thanks for any help

Comment: why are you not using the `[1, 2, 3]` notation for lists?

Answer (score 4):

You could do:

```
zipWith (\x -> map (const x)) [1..] thisList
```

Example usage:

```
Prelude> let thisList = [[1], [1,1], [1,1,1]]
Prelude> zipWith (\x -> map (const x)) [1..] thisList
[[1],[2,2],[3,3,3]]
```

Or simpler:

```
zipWith (map . const) [1..] thisList
```

---

It's quite easy. `zipWith f as bs` is equivalent to `map (uncurry f) $ zip as bs`. So we have:

```
zip [1..] thisList == [(1, [1]), (2, [1,1,]), (3, [1,1,1])]
```

Then we apply `f` to each pair and so:

```
map (const 1) [1]   == [const 1 1] == [1]
map (const 2) [1,1] == [const 2 1, const 2 1] == [2,2]
map (const 3) [1,1,1] == [const 3 1, const 3 1, const 3 1] == [3,3,3]
```

---

*If* you meant that a sublist of length `n` should be replaced by `[n, n, ..., n]` of length `n`, as in:

```
thisList = [[1, 1], [1], [1], [1, 1, 1]]
result = [[2,2], [1], [1], [3,3,3]]
```

then you have to change approach:

```
map (\xs -> let len = length xs in replicate len len) thisList
```

Example:

```
Prelude> let thisList = [[1, 1], [1], [1], [1, 1, 1]]
Prelude> map (\xs -> let len = length xs in replicate len len) thisList
[[2,2],[1],[1],[3,3,3]]
```